# how to execute ftp command " put 'FILE_NAME' " using python script

Tags: python, file, file-transfer

how do I execute ftp command " put 'FILE_NAME' " using python script?

I want to transfer a file to the processor connected using FTP.

Command is ftp> put "C:\filename"

I want this to be executed using python script. Please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import call

call(['echo "put C:\filename" | ftp'])
```

this should call "ftp" command and pass input string "put C:\filename"